# How to share objects between two git repos that have almost the same history?

Tags: git

I have two remote repos A and B. B is separated from A not a long time ago, so they basically have the same commit history. Now I already have a local clone of A, and added B as another remote, but when I do

```
git fetch B
```

its trying to re-download all the objects from B.

Is there a way to make it re-use the objects in A and only fetch the objects I dont have locally from B?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps:

1. repo checkout B
2. repo checkout A
3. repo merge B

Now only the changes which are there in repo B will be merged to repo A

Comment: thanks, but I am not sure i understand, and two repos are bare repos.

Comment: This will basically merge repo B to repo A from the point when repo B was branched out

Comment: sorry, i dont see how this is about merging at all

Comment: Let's say you have 2 repos which were in sync at some point of time.
Now again you are trying to sync them up?
If some objects are in B and not in A then repo merge B will fetch these objects onto A

Comment: to be clear, i am not trying to sync them up, they were separated for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what `git`s notion of "alternate object directories" is for - they can be enabled using an environment variable (`GIT_ALTERNATE_OBJECT_DIRECTORIES`) for short term use, or in `.git/objects/info/alternates` for more permanent use. They don't seem to be widely documented, which makes me think they may not be entirely straightforward to use in certain situations. But they basically are a list of separate directories where a particular object might be stored, and are searched as necessary to find them...

You can do `git help gitrepository-layout` or `git help git` to find some more information.

Comment: thanks, "alternates" seems to only work for the case where you reference a different local clone of the same repo. But in my case, i am simply adding B as another remote in the same clone of A, I tried creating an "alternates" file there and add "../../" as a path, "git fetch B" still downloads quite a lot of objects.